# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh'

Tags: python, subprocess, errno, netsh

This is my python Code to see the Devices connected to my WIFI:

```
  import subprocess

  meta_data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])
  data = meta_data.decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace")
  data = data.split('\n')
  names = []

  for i in data:
      if "All Users Profiles" in i:
          i = i.split(":")
          i = i[1]
          i = i[1:-1]
          names.append(i)
  print("Systems Connected To Your WIFI ARE ")
  print()
  for name in names:
      print(name)
```

AND this is the error I keep getting after i run the code:

```
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh'
```

Comment: What exactly is `netsh`?

Comment: @klaus D.    Netsh is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to display or modify the network configuration of a computer that is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it through the shell using `cmd.exe /c` or by passing `shell=true` into `check_output`. The `subprocess` package does not run in a shell by default on Windows.

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["dir"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>> subprocess.check_output(["cmd.exe","/c","dir"])
b' ... '
>>> subprocess.check_output(["dir"], shell=True)
b' ... '
```

This is only something you need to do on Windows.

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["ls"])
b' ... '
```

Comment: it fixes the ERROR but it doesn't show me the devices that connected the the wifi, it just show me the print("") result. can you please help!. Thank You

Comment: Your code is looking for "All Users Profiles" but the actual output of `netsh` prints "All User Profile". Your code works for me when I make that change.