# No such file or directory: 'netsh'

Tags: python

I am trying to write code that can get wifi passwords but when I run it it shows this error in VSC (Visual Studio Code).

```py
import subprocess

meta_data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])

data = meta_data.decode('utf-8', errors ="backslashreplace")

data = data.split('\n')

profiles = []

for i in data:

if "All User Profile" in i :
    i = i.split(":")
    i = i[1]
    i = i[1:-1]
    
    profiles.append(i)
          
print("{:<30}| {:<}".format("Wi-Fi Name", "Password"))
print("----------------------------------------------")
   
for i in profiles:

    try:
        results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key = clear'])
     
        results = results.decode('utf-8', errors ="backslashreplace")
        results = results.split('\n')
     
        results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
     
        try:
            print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
     
        except IndexError:
            print("{:<30}| {:<}".format(i, ""))
         

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("Encoding Error Occurred")
```

However it shows this error:

```
No such file or directory: 'netsh'
```

Could someone help me fix this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can check this link;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983496/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-netsh

Comment: An alternative approach might be to use this package https://pypi.org/project/ifcfg/?